# Delete from Laravel Database using button

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel

Im trying to delete rows from an sqlite database and then refresh the page. This should all happen when i click the button(shown bellow).

Button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick= "{{{ url("delete_item_action/$post->Id") }}}">Delete</button>
```

Here are the functions that should execute the sql query delete:

```
function delete_Post($id)
{
 $sql = "delete FROM Post WHERE id = ?";
 DB::delete($sql, array($id));
} 
function delete_item_action($id)
{
  delete_Post($id);
  return View::make('social.home');
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because the onclick parameter is a javascript function, which the browser tries to execute but since there is only a url there, it will probably fail with an "undefined" error.

You have multiple ways to achieve what you want:

1. Make a form

```html
<form action="{{{ url('your url')}}}">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</input>
</form>
```

2. Make an anchor

(It's not tested, don't know if this will work)

```html
<a href="{{{ url('your-url') }}}"><button>...</button></a>
```

3. Call a javascript function which changes the current location

```html
<button ... onclick="window.location.href={{{ url('your-url') }}}">...</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use jquery and ajax to submit your request asynchronously:

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
function delete_post( id ) {
  console.log('firing delete post');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'delete_onclick/'+id,
    method: 'post',
  }).done( function( data ) {
    alert(data);
  });
}
</script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_post(2)">Delete</button>
```

And your routes

```
Route::get('onclick', function() { return View::make('onclick'); });
Route::post('delete_onclick/{id}', function($id) {
  // Post::find($id)->delete(); or something similar
  return "Deleted entry";
});
```